# Test parent-child bidirectional relations using PHPSpec

Tags: php, phpspec

How to test with phpspec that parent-child biedirectional relations are created properly?

```
class ParentSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_adds_a_reference_to_self_while_(Child $child)
    {
        $this->addChild($child);

        $child->setParent($this)->shouldBeCalled();
    }
}
```

Line 7 throws an error, which is obious because `$this` is a `ParentSpec` object not `Parent`. But I have no other ideas how to test that `setParent` method has been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getWrappedObject to get the underlying object:

```
$child->setParent($this->getWrappedObject())->shouldBeCalled();
```

http://www.phpspec.net/en/latest/cookbook/wrapped-objects.html